# Trigger update of ScanResult android wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is it possible to trigger an update of the scan result for wifi on an Android phone? So when you use the example code below you dont get cashed values.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.startScan();

List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```